# Capture the space key in Go without following enter

Tags: go, io, std

I am looking for a lightweight and in the best case pure go implementation to capture <kbd>space</kbd> without a following <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I have seen some people using C as extern in Go or [termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox). Is there really no other method of capturing every keyboard stroke?

I have already thought about opening the device directly (in Linux) and trying to read from there.

Any advice of how to do this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, it's hard to come up with a perfect example of what you're looking for.  However, the basic idea is that you need to switch your terminal into raw mode, where input is passed immediately to your application.  [`x/crypto/ssh/terminal`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal) is a popular library that provides this functionality:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    oldState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, oldState)
    for {
        var oneChar [1]byte
        _, err := os.Stdin.Read(oneChar[:])
        const ETX = '\x03' // ^C
        const EOT = '\x04' // ^D
        if err != nil || oneChar[0] == ETX || oneChar[0] == EOT {
            break
        }
        if oneChar[0] == ' ' {
            fmt.Println("Space pressed!\r")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This sounds promising. I will give it a try.